# Crystal load capacitor physical defect

Tags: capacitor, soldering, crystal, pll

I have a 16MHz crystal that is used to derive a 60MHz PLL.

I have not seen many issues but have a PCBA that loses its PLL lock. I'm not sure why but I looked at one of the load capacitors up close (18pF) and I see some metal along the side of the component.

[image: Load capacitor with metal on edge]

Could this be the cause of the loss of PLL lock? Why might that be?

Comment: You could try to use an Ohmmeter to confirm there's a short.

Comment: Unlikely. Is that even solder, or just flux that looks like metal under scope? There can be several other explanations for losing lock, such as incorrectly chosen parts, incorrect schematics, incorrect PCB design, or some manufacturing error on any part including components related to crystal or power supply. This board could be defective due to one component somewhere being out of spec, or, all boards may be barely working and close to being in error. Show the schematics, PCB design, and list of components.

Comment: Can you confirm it's an 18p capacitor? I recently came across a PCBA from far east, and there were 100n caps placed as XTAL load caps.